# how can I remove slidingmenu?

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I don't know how I can stop sliding menu. I'd like to remove the slide menu that can swipe. I tried to annotate in code. But I couldn't stop acting slidemenu.

Below are my codes. Can you help me? Thanks so much in advance! :)

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener  {
    private final long  FINSH_INTERVAL_TIME    = 2000;
    private long        backPressedTime        = 0;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;


    ViewPager mViewPager;
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            finish();
            return;
            }
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);              
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        //getActionBar().hide();
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
//
//      // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
//
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();


        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                //invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                //invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

                // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
                // primary sections of the app.
                mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                        getSupportFragmentManager());


                // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
                mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
                mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
                mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
                // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
                // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
                // a reference to the Tab.
                mViewPager
                        .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                                getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                            }
                        });

                // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
                //for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
                    // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
                    // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
                    // this tab is selected.
                getActionBar().setStackedBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.background));
                getActionBar().addTab(getActionBar().newTab()
                            //.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(0))
                            .setTabListener(this)
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.tmon)
                            //.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(0))
                            );

                    getActionBar().addTab(getActionBar().newTab()
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.coupang)
                            //.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(1))
                            .setTabListener(this));


                    getActionBar().addTab(getActionBar().newTab()
                            //.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(2))
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.wemef)
                            .setTabListener(this));

                    getActionBar().addTab(getActionBar().newTab()
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.oclock)
                            //.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(3))
                            .setTabListener(this));
                    //getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.tmon);
                //}
                    getActionBar().addTab(getActionBar().newTab()
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.search)
                            //.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(4))
                            .setTabListener(this));


    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }
    //tab
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }


    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }


    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        Context mContext;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            switch(position) {
            case 0:
                return new Tab1();
            case 1:
                return new Tab2();
            case 2:
                return new Tab3();
            case 3:
                return new Tab4();
            case 4:
                return new Tab5();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 5 total pages.
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
            case 4:
                return getString(R.string.title_section5).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the Navigation Drawer you should look inside the Layout XML and remove drawer layout from there